# How to exclude a void type on a union type?

Tags: typescript

Hello guys I have a custom generic type `P` that is defined like this `P extends Record<string, unknown> | void`

And I want to have an `exists` function

```
export class Parameters<P extends Record<string, unknown> | void> {
        private params: P
        constructor(params: P) {
                this.params = params 
        }
        public exists(field: keyof P): boolean {
                return field in this.params
        }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUVRQW2BmCjQB4s5RiA7AE0wCVgFo6y0YoBLGgcwA0cAK40A1jQgB3GgD44AHzgA3CNzryA3gFgAUHAOGDYHspTE4YXATQAubHqNHWNTlGEIY0ABRW8+O2wASjgdfScIoxgAC240ADo-GzgAXktrALhHSIBfbIiwYQAjJG4EKhA4mDRvADNuYCQ6eywg+yKICCRgFBpQ-MiIqCJhKD76xro4XjgYuMSMtAGjPN0coA)

But I obviously got a compilation error when running a `tsc` because I can't do it on the `void` type. How can I get rid of it inside my `exists` function?

`tsc`
Typescript version 4.9.3
Thanks!

[image: compilation error]

Comment: Why is it void, how can you pass a void parameter, Why don't use undefined and have a condition inside the function

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example, since when I paste your code into a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB5agw), I get an error that is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: There's no error in the linked playground...

Comment: Indeed, but I have one running an `npm run build` which does a `tsc` and Typescript is in version `4.9.3`

Comment: Why do you  have `void` in the first place?

Comment: It's used to define an `EndpointSpec`
```export type EndpointSpec<
  Param extends Record<string, unknown> | void,
  Result extends Record<string, unknown> | void,
  ThenResult,
> = {
  /** defaults to 'get' */
  method: HttpVerb
  path: ((args: Parameters<Param, Result, ThenResult>) => string) | string
  then: (body: Result, args: Param) => ThenResult
}
>```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249711/discussion-between-nainpo-and-cats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure params in not `undefined`

```
export class Parameters<P extends Record<string, unknown> | void> {
    params!: P
    public exists(field: P): boolean {
        return this.params && field in this.params
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUVRQW2BmCjQB4s5RiA7AE0wCVgFo6y0YoBLGgcwA0cAK40A1jQgB3GgD44AHzgA3CNzryA3gCg4euGFwE0AQgBc2XfrDCARkm4IqIbpzQAKAGbdgSOhawASgtbCAgkYBQaOB19OLgoImEoaJgAC1cAOkM8fEwAMny4b186OF44dKyc4ys9AF9teqA)

Comment: This does the trick thanks!
Figuring if I can get rid of the `Void` now before accepting it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: In Typescript `4.9.3` this gave me another error handled by this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51501)
Needed to do also check the type 
`return this.params && typeof this.params === 'object' && field in this.params`